# PHP MySQL How to get the count of rows where column is completely unique

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
id          +        kID       
--------------------------
0           |         3
1           |         6
2           |         7
3           |         6
4           |         7
5           |         5
```

What I want to do is find the amount of rows where the `kID` occurs only once.  So in this case the value of the variable should be `2` because `kID: 3 and 5 occurs only once` so i'm trying to count that while ignoring everything else.  I am really stumped, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will show `kID`s that occur only once:

```
SELECT kID, COUNT(kID)
FROM table
GROUP BY kID
HAVING COUNT(kID) < 2
```

**Result**

```
| KID | COUNT(KID) |
--------------------
|   3 |          1 |
|   5 |          1 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69cbf/2)

Then to get the total count of those:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count 
FROM   (SELECT kid, 
               Count(kid) 
        FROM   tbl 
        GROUP  BY kid 
        HAVING Count(kid) < 2) a
```

**Result**

```
| COUNT |
---------
|     2 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69cbf/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
  id,
  count(kID) as `Count`
FROM mytable as t
GROUP BY kID
HAVING Count = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select count(*) from 
(select kid, count(*) from table group by kid having count(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
select count(*) from 
(
    select kID, COUNT(*) [c] from tableName
    group by kID
) t
where t.c = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT kID, 
COUNT(kID) 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY kID
HAVING COUNT(kID) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a sub-select. This should work, though might not be extremely efficient:

```
SELECT id, kID, COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT COUNT(1),kID FROM TABLE
                               GROUP BY kID
                               HAVING COUNT = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it. It will work as long as the `(id)` is the primary key of the table or there is a unique constraint on `(kid, id)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  ( SELECT NULL
    FROM tableX
    GROUP BY kid
    HAVING MIN(id) = MAX(id) 
  ) AS g ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b02fc/2)**

An index on `(kid, id)` will improve efficiency - and only one `COUNT()` will be done, not 2.